# Finding the next value in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to have a user activated "Next Site" button that advances the value of a cell through a defined range of cells from another sheet. Everytime the button is pressed it should return the value of the next item in the range

So far I have :

```
Sub NextSite()
 Set EXCEPTION = Sheets("EXCEPTION")
 Set CONTROL = Sheets("CONTROL")
 Dim rCell As Range
 Dim rRng As Range

 CurrentVal = EXCEPTION.Range("B16")

 Set rRng = CONTROL.Range("B9:B72")

 For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If CurrentVal = rCell.Value Then
        GoTo NextCell
        Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = CONTROL.Range(rCell.Address)
        Exit For
    End If
NextCell:
Next rCell

End Sub
```

While I think I have the beginning of an idea here I can't quite get the flow of working through the range.

I would also like to have the a separate code that finds the previous Site in the list if anyone can offer advice for that.

Comment: See [THIS](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) Especially SECTION 3

Comment: a static variable to hold the currently displayed site?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question..In this example we want to sequentially sample from a range called **rLook**.  The range is a disjoint set of cells (the worst case), but the macro will work on any range.  We use a static variable to sample index:

```
Dim Kounter As Long
Sub sequentialSamples()
    Dim rLook As Range, r As Range
    Set rLook = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1,B9,C13,F1,J66")
    If Kounter = 0 Or Kounter > rLook.Count Then
        Kounter = 1
    End If
    j = 0
    For Each r In rLook
        j = j + 1
        If j = Kounter Then
            MsgBox Kounter & vbCrLf & r.Address & vbCrLf & r.Value
            Kounter = Kounter + 1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, however in testing I find that it just returns the first value in the rLook range every time.  
  
In my flawed attempt above I have captured the name of the current site in the ActiveCell as CurrentValue and this may appear as 5th in the range. I need to amend the code so that when the user presses a button the ActiveCell updates to the 6th value. 

Conversely I will be looking to create a reverse option so that if the ActiveCell is the same as the 5th in the range then a separate button will change the ActiveCell to the 4th in the range.  
  
HTH :)